# I have two fields in one Object, Field1 and Field2.

Tags: app-development

I have one question.
I have two fields in one Object, Field1 and Field2. If My Field1=LOW then Field2 is Updated with 25, Field1=Medium then Field2 is Updated with 50 and Field1=High then Field2 is Updated with 75.
How to achieve this in salesforce.

Comment: Try using formula field.

Comment: Is Field1 a picklist?

Comment: Field1 is PICKLIST

Answer (score 0):

You can make filed1 as a formula of field2. 
Refer this https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Field1` is a **Picklist** you can use a formula field (`Field2`) with the following logic.

```
IF( ISPICKVAL( Field1__c , 'High') , 75', 
IF( ISPICKVAL( Field1__c , 'Medium') , '50', 
IF( ISPICKVAL( Field1__c , 'Low') , '25', 
'' 
)))
```

Using 3 If statements to check the picklist value and updating `Field2` as requested. This would now be considered as an old approach but for beginners it may be easier to understand.

A newer approach (Winter '06) to this condition logic would be to use `Case` functions. Here is an example using your requirements. Again `Field1` being a Picklist and `Field2` a formula.

```
CASE(Field1__c, 
"High", "75", 
"Medium", "50", 
"Low", "25", 
"")
```

Comment: Or use a Workflow with criteria `ISCHANGED( Field1__c )` to update Field2 value